# Replace Unavailable Images via CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

Is it possible to replace the standard broken image via CSS or using another technique? All my images are the same size and my have transparency.

I've tried to wrap all images with a div's background:

```
<div class="no_broken">
  <img src="http://www.web.com/found.gif"/>
</div>

<div class="no_broken">
  <img src="http://www.web.com/notfound.gif"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.no_broken { 
  background-image: url(standard.gif); 
}

div.no_broken, div.no_broken img { 
  width: 32px; 
  height: 32px; 
  display: block; 
}
```

But this will display two images on top of each other if the IMG is transparent.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This works without CSS:

```
<img src="some.jpg" onerror="this.src='alternative.jpg';">
```

It seems to even work when Javascript is disabled.

Comment: that's odd. looks like javascript to me :/ Oh well. that's not the first nor last odd feature found in browsers

Comment: THis does not work when JavaScript is disabled. And it will cause an infinite loop if the alternative.jpg is accidentally missing.

Comment: To do this purely using CSS, you can check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:-moz-broken, then find the equivalent for the other browsers that you are targeting.

Comment: This will work but if the `alternative.jpg` images is also unavailable the browser will make infinite number of requests for it. For that reason I prefer  the answer from broox below.

Comment: To eliminate the infinite number of requests for `alternative.jpg`, change the error handler to this:

`<img src="some.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=''; this.src='alternative.jpg';">`

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can replace an image with CSS, using a trick of pseudo selectors.

Basically, `::before` and `::after` only apply when the image fails to load. You can use absolute positioning to place the CSS pseudo element over the broken image placeholder:

```css
img {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

    img::before {
        content: 'fall back';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        line-height: 200px;
        background-color: #fd0;
        color: currentColor;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 2px;
        display: block;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<img src="not-found">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
```

This snippet works with no JS at all, but only works in newer browsers.

Comment: Unbelievable. I guess the ::before property covers over the standard error icon. Magnificent.

Comment: While the accepted answer may have been accurate at the time, this is the best current solution. This should be the new selected answer.

Comment: @Polyducks Yes, `img::before.background-color` covers up the standard error icon in this case because it's a fully opaque color. Using any transparency lets the error show through.

Comment: its amazing solution but if you use img as absolute position. then this solution will not works. cause relative property is changed... :/ any idea?

Comment: @sawacrow it works if the `img` is `absolute`, so long as it's a new positioning context so that the `::before` is absolutely positioned relative to the `img`, rather than the page.

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to add some javascript into the mix, this should work well with jQuery to detect image errors and add some sort of error state CSS class to the broken images.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.no_broken img').error(function () {
        $(this).addClass('broken');
    });
});
```

And then in your CSS you could have something like

```
div.no_broken, div.no_broken img { 
  width: 32px; 
  height: 32px; 
  display: block; 
}

div.no_broken img.broken {
    background-image: url(standard.gif);
    content:"";
}
```

Comment: I like this but setting the broken image's `content: ""` or `display: none` caused other layout issues for me. Using `opacity: 0` solved that problem.

Answer (score 3):

Thought I'd package the comment from **kmoser** into an answer. Clearing the onerror handler is a good idea as loops are possible.

Javascript

```
function epic(c) {
    c.onerror='';
    c.src='alternative.jpg';
};
```

HTML

```
<img src='some.jpg' onerror='epic(this)'>
```

We drop this epic function into all our image tags now on [twiends](http://twiends.com), as we pull in loads of social profile images that all expire at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I don't what technology you are using but in ASP.net there is something called control adapters.

I have used this to capture the PreRender of all images and replace the imageurl if the imageurl is not complete.

I don't know if this relates at all to your situation and certainly will not work when there is a path but not image at the path.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no CSS property that controls the display of broken images.  Maybe there are browser-specific properties?  You may have to resort to Javascript to iterate the images on the page, and replace their src if they are broken.